# 1 or more object with the same name?

Tags: java

I have possibly gotten the title wrong but I don't know what else to say.

Our lecturer gave us this code today:

```
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter an amount for a new account, or anything else to end: ");
        if(in.hasNextInt()) {
            int openBalance = in.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter account name: ");
            String name = in.next();
            // part I don't understand
            BankAccount newAccount = new BankAccount(name, openBalance); 
            bankAccountList.add(newAccount);
            // part I don't understand
        } else {
            finished = true;
        }
    } while(!finished);
```

I understand everything apart from what is in bold (Well what should be bold but it is code so), pretty much we have to make as many bank accounts as the user wants until something other than an int is inputted.

BUT wouldn't

```
 BankAccount newAccount = new BankAccount(name, openBalance);
```

create an object with the same name as the previous account made?
if someone could please explain the code then that would be amazing. Thank you.

Comment: are you asking about the name in the `BankAccount` object or about the   name of the variable: `newAccount`?

Answer (score 2):

```
String name = in.next();
```

`name` should be different in each iteration of the loop (as the user enters a new name in each iteration), so each account would have a different name.

Of course the user may enter the same name twice, which would create two accounts with the same name, but that's a different issue.

Comment: oh, so objects do not need to have unique names? this is making a lot more sense now..

I think i need a little brush up on my java.

Comment: It is just a matter of *scope*

Comment: @CeriWestcott If you are referring to `newAccount` as the "object name", that's merely a variable that refers to an object. It can refer to a different object in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about local variables. In your case, your creating local objects, which are valid only for one interation. they can be created again because, in next iteration previous objects are invalidated.

Comment: Ah right! I had always been taught(self taught) that say I wanted 2 bank accounts. I'd have to do

BankAccount Ceri = new BankAccount(Name, age, ...);
BankAccount Whoever = new BankAccount(Name, age, ...);

Answer (score 0):

The whole code is in a loop. For every iteration User has to enter open balance (int value) and Name (String value). These two values are used as parameters to create object of type BankAccount.

So every time the object is created with the values entered by the user. The iteration will end if the user enters some non integer value for open balance.